# Modifying the HTML request from the kernel, WFP?

Tags: html, http, driver, alter, wfp

I've developed a driver with "Windows Filter Platform (WFP)", the program filters the HTML and adds to the body a little string, like the mark of a company.

The filter works fine, but I have a problem, when the HTTP has:

> Transfer-Encoding: chunked

then the web page doesn't load, the web browser said that "can't show the web page"

when the HTTP defines a lenght like this

> Content-Length: 9977

the page loads but it omits data of the original HTML with the size of the string that I inserted at the end of the HTML

I think this is because of I'm altering the size of the data. but I don't know if only altering the size in the HTTP HEADER will work, or I have to modify it since the IP or TCP HEADERs

I don't know how the browser works in these cases

any idea?,

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, yes the problem was the new size of the body, and modifying the size of the content in either case, the page loads correctly

Comment: And what did you do about chunk problem?

Comment: @Javid I ask for the full data, not chunked. But, I'm going to update my code, so if I find a way to accomplish that, I'll tell you how to.

Comment: Thank you :) I'll wait for it.